# Unexpected difference between IEnumerable and List as result of a linq-statement in .net-core?

Tags: c#, list, linq, .net-core

When I add .ToList() at the end of the Select() statement it works as expected.
What's the difference between IEnumerable and List in this case?

```
class Foo{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var list = new List<string>(){ "first", "last" };
        var bar = list.Select(x => new Foo {
            Name = x,
            Id = Guid.NewGuid()
        }); //.ToList();
        Console.WriteLine("bar Count = " + bar.Count());
        Console.WriteLine();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) { 
            Console.WriteLine(bar.First().Name + " " + bar.First().Id);
            Console.WriteLine(bar.Last().Name + " " + bar.Last().Id);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

**Result:**

examples Count = 2

first 1fabd003-340c-44a4-81ca-1908f206ccdb
last 213f40c9-0705-4676-ad1f-73de21c5bc62

first 9bc117e5-1f10-4855-af95-46258b39955c
last cd787227-12d9-4e25-88bc-634369d85671

first c787e081-8dd3-475c-bf24-44e5f103ed3a
last 7a72080d-2dee-47b1-a55d-af0a7665d0ea

**Result with .ToList()**

bar Count = 2

first 3c1d4f1d-eecd-438a-86a4-e7db0680cad3
last cba1867d-d246-477e-b938-0f9cce457a5c

first 3c1d4f1d-eecd-438a-86a4-e7db0680cad3
last cba1867d-d246-477e-b938-0f9cce457a5c

first 3c1d4f1d-eecd-438a-86a4-e7db0680cad3
last cba1867d-d246-477e-b938-0f9cce457a5c

Comment: The question is not entirely clear, but I'm guessing it has something to do with the fact that a `Select` LINQ query defers action until enumerated. You're enumerating it when you add `ToList`

Comment: It seems to be that you're confusing `IEnumerable` and collection. `IEnumerable` is not really a collection but more like a draft of one, it contains `IEnumerator` - the object that *knows* how to enumerate collections. Only when we execute a function that requires to enumerate it does it actually execute anything and `.ToList()` enumerates it and returns a collection while `.First` executes it and returns first element

Comment: I've been saying this for over a decade and it seems like every day it still needs to be repeated. **A query object represents a question, not an answer**.  You can ask the same question twice and get a different answer! In your original code you are asking the question three times. In your modified code you are asking it once and caching the result.

Comment: Similarly we could say `Func<Guid> f = Guid.NewGuid;` and we would discover that `Console.WriteLine($"{f()}{f()}{f()}");` and `g = f(); Console.WriteLine($"{g}{g}{g}");` have different behaviour. Does this case surprise you, or would that be a difference that you expect?

Answer (score 5):

When you use `Select`, you are defining a *lazy enumerable*, meaning you are defining rules on how the values in the enumerable are generated but are not yet actually generating the values themselves. Lazy enumerables (a.k.a. "deferred") are blueprints and nothing more - they contain no data and execute no code.

Following this, when you call `bar.First()` and `bar.Last()`, you are triggering the enumerable to start generating some values. *Each time you do this, it is going to generate completely new values.* That means that every time you call something on `bar`, it is going to generate new values with new calls to `Guid.NewGuid()`, and naturally that will result in new GUIDs being generated every time.

However, if you call `ToList()` on your enumerable, you are generating the values in the enumerable *and then caching them in a `List`*. Now when you call `bar.First()` and `bar.Last()`, you are referring to the static values of the first and last elements in the `List` which do not change.

Answer (score 2):

`System.Linq` uses deferred execution. When you use `IEnumerable`, a new `Foo` values are generated every time, when you iterate over enumerable in a loop, with the new `Id` value for every instance. When you call `First()` or `Last()`, you get a new instance with different `Guid` value.

When `ToList()` is used, the `Linq` expression is evaluated immediately and `Foo` instances remains the same in collection, with the `Id` value already calculated. Your loop iterates over the collection with the same values, `First()` and `Last()` returns the same instance at every `for` loop iteration. Therefore you are getting the same `Guid` values every time.

You can put a breakpoint in `Id` property setter an see how many times the value is set in case of `IEnumerable` and `List`

Answer (score 1):

You have the creation of your objects inside your `IEnumerable`, everytime you enumerate it, it creates new items. Your Calls to `First()` and `Last()` might generate two different iterations, generation different content.

If you store it before with `ToList`, the content stays the same on each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

```
var bar = list.Select(x => new Foo {
    Name = x,
    Id = Guid.NewGuid()
});
```

Every time the GetEnumerator method on the `bar` value is called it will produce an enumerator that executes the function for each element in `list`. Since you have a Guid.NewGuid() in the middle, it is unstable.

```
Console.WriteLine("bar Count = " + bar.Count());
Console.WriteLine(bar.First().Name + " " + bar.First().Id);
Console.WriteLine(bar.Last().Name + " " + bar.Last().Id);
```

Each of these lines calls an extension method that calls `GetEnumerator()`, which resulted in 5 different GUIDs being generated (`First()` is smart and stops after the first one).

```
var bar = list.Select(x => new Foo {
    Name = x,
    Id = Guid.NewGuid()
}).ToList();
```

This makes a `List<Foo>` from the result of running the SelectEnumerable once.  Each call to GetEnumerator from the extension methods gets the same stable data, because the List already has its element values.